# Event study - Standardized Cumulative Abnormal Return Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I am conducting an event study and have difficulties testing CAR values.

My estimation window length (L1) = 252, event window (L2) = 11. 
I followed the market model when calculating abnormal returns L1 and L2.
I aggregated abnormal return in the event window to get CARs for 11 days.
For testing CAR values, I used the formulas below:

[image]
[image]

For S(AR)^2 I used ARs from the estimation window only and L2 is from the event window.

To get the significance of [-1, 2], do I need to simply add up SCAR(-1) + SCAR(0) + SCAR(1) + SCAR(2) to see if it is below or above p critical value?

Thank you!